# Joomla backend popup suddelly messed up

Tags: javascript, joomla, popup, joomla3.0

All of a sudden one of my customers website begun to behave strangely.
All popups in Joomla backend stopped working (needless to say, he "didn't touch anything")

Adding an image in an article, or inserting page breaks, or any other button that opens a popup creates a popup window with garbled characters, or creats a Javascript alert with garbled characters as well.
Any editor behaves the same.

(see attached images)
Any idea?

Joomla 3.4.3 on windows

[image: Popup error]

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be cache issue or htaccess.  
- For cache, try installing the Web Developer Toolbar: http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/ Once installed, click on it's Sprocket icon, then go to OPTIONS->RESET PAGE
- For htaccess, try reverting back to Joomla htaccess (or temporarily just removing) to see if the problem persists.

Comment: I don't think it's a cache or htacces issue...I am talking about bakend...not frontend.

However, deleting cache was the first thing I did...

Comment: I have had both cause issues on backend when htaccess has additional rules for backend security and in general for cache.  If you have JCE or other 3rd party editor, make sure it is updated or reinstall.

Comment: JCE was already up-to-date. I have upgraded joomla to 3.6.5 manually overwriting Joomal core files, popup issues disappeared...

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded this joomla installation manually going from 3.4.3 to 3.6.5

Popup issues disappeared, but I am still getting some Javascript alerts...